# Bind header width of one datagrid with header width of other datagrid

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid, styles

I have two grid like below

```
<DataGrid ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" GridLinesVisibility="All" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#bdced4" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#bdced4" 
                RowHeaderWidth="41" HeadersVisibility="All" x:Name="MonitorListHeader" Loaded="MonitorList_Loaded" LoadingRow="dg_LoadingRow" 
                CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" 
                CanUserReorderColumns="False" SelectionUnit="Cell" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="75" Header="ID">
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn 
                    Width="{Binding ElementName=CableColumn, Path=ActualWidth}" 
                    Header="Cable">
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" Header="Port/IP">
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" Header="Status">
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>    
            </DataGrid.Columns>                
        </DataGrid>

<DataGrid ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" GridLinesVisibility="All" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#bdced4" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#bdced4" 
                RowHeaderWidth="41" HeadersVisibility="All" x:Name="MonitorList" Loaded="MonitorList_Loaded" LoadingRow="dg_LoadingRow" 
                CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" 
                CanUserReorderColumns="False" SelectionUnit="Cell" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="75" Header="ID">
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="CableColumn"
                    Width="*" Header="Cable">
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" Header="Port/IP">
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" Header="Status">
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>    
            </DataGrid.Columns>                
        </DataGrid>
```

Now I want to bind  2nd grid's 3rd column's header width with the  1std grid's 3rd column's header width.

Can anyone please tell me the binding code for this?

Thanks !!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I renamed the elements to make it clearer:

XAML:

```
... First DataGrid ...
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" Header="Cable" x:Name="SourceColumn" />
...

...Second DataGrid ...
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" Header="Cable" x:Name="TargetColumn" />
...
```

Code behind (in the constructor, just after `InitializeComponent();`):

```
var binding = new Binding("Width");
binding.Source = SourceColumn;
binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(TargetColumn, DataGridColumn.WidthProperty, binding);
```

I looked for a pure XAML solution but I wasn't working.

Comment: Thanks for your time. But where are you binding the 1st datagri'd column width with 2nd datagrid's column header width.

Comment: The binding is set up by the call to `SetBindind()`. Did you try it ? It works as you asked: the widths of the 'Cable' columns are synchronized.